# Conditionally showing HTML without wrapping it in a PHP echo statement

Tags: php, html

I have a block of code to generate a user's profile that looks like this:

```
<?php
    if($user_isbanned) {
        echo 'User is banned.';
        exit(1);
    }
?>
<!-- Content to show if the user is not banned -->
```

This works for what I want it to do (stop the profile from appearing if the user's account is banned), but if I were to add in a footer at the bottom of the page, it would not appear on a banned user's page since the exit() statement aborted generating the rest of the page. I could reformat my code to look like this:

```
<?php
    if($user_isbanned) {
        echo 'User is banned.';
    } else {
        // Content to show if the user is not banned
    }
?>
```

This would make my footer appear regardless of whether or not the user is banned, but I don't want to wrap the entire page in one large PHP echo statement. Is there anyway to prevent a certain block of HTML from appearing if a PHP condition is or is not satisfied, without putting the entire page in an echo statement?

Comment: I'd suggest put the footer in a separate file then include it as needed.

Comment: You can start and stop PHP mode as many times as you want, if that's your question.

Comment: `<?php if($user_isbanned): ?> ... stuff ... <?php else: ?> ... other stuff ... <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: You can redirect user if he's banned and show the page when he is not

Comment: ^ that's a better idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, a footer will never be displayed. In fact, not even a closing `</html>` tag, that doesn't seem very desirable.

You don't have to literally `echo` the HTML, you could just:

```
<?php
    if($user_isbanned) {
        echo 'User is banned.';
    } else {
?>

<!-- html goes here -->

<?php
    }
?>
```

Alternatively, you could just redirect a banned user to a separate page entirely.

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is something like that:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>

    <?php if($user_isbanned){ ?>
        <div id="content-banned"></div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div id="content-not-banned"></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Just render different kind of content, when user is banned.

Comment: This is probably the best method although for readability in a HTML page I prefer if(): elseif(): else: and endif; as they look more like HTML tags. Just preferences though.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution would be an HTTP redirection to an informative page:

```
<?php
if($user_isbanned) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/banned');
    exit(1);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you prefer to keep your current design:

```
<?php
    if($user_isbanned) {
        echo 'User is banned.';
    } else {
?>
    <p>Content to show if the user is not banned</p>
<?php
}
```

N.B. Closing `?>` tag is optional.